# Android Intent in Preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a Pro and a Free Version of my App.
Both have a Backup Activity but I don't want the Android Activity Chooser to show up when a user has both versions installed.
Therefore I have created two product flavors (free and pro) which have two different preferences.xml's

In the pro preferences.xml I use this intent to show the Datamanagement Activity:

```
 <PreferenceCategory
    android:key="datamanagement_category"
    android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:summary="@string/settings_datamanagement_message"
        android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >
        <intent android:action="com.sourcecastle.logbook.DataManagementActivity" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>

 <activity
        android:name="com.sourcecastle.logbook.DataManagementActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/datamanagement_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sourcecastle.logbook.DataManagementActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In the free product flavor I use just a empty subclass of the same Datamanagement Activity:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="datamanagement_category"
    android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >


    <PreferenceScreen
        android:summary="@string/settings_datamanagement_message"
        android:title="@string/settings_datamanagement_title" >
        <intent android:action="com.sourcecastle.logbook.FreeDataManagementActivity" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>


  <activity
        android:name="com.sourcecastle.logbook.FreeDataManagementActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/datamanagement_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sourcecastle.logbook.FreeDataManagementActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The product flavors definately work correct since I tried to change the Activity title in one flavor.
Why does the Android Intent Chooser still show up?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Can you please post the code how you create a chooser intent?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the most important :(